# Create nested JSON of all rows having same Id: DataFrame

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame `df4` with three column

1. `id` annotating entity
2. `data` having JSON Array data
3. `executor_id` as string value

Code to create same is as follow:

```
val df1 = Seq((1, "n1", "d1")).toDF("id",  "number", "data")

val df2 = df1.withColumn("data", to_json(struct($"number", $"data"))).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"data").alias("data")).withColumn("executor_id", lit("e1"))

val df3 = df1.withColumn("data", to_json(struct($"number", $"data"))).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"data").alias("data")).withColumn("executor_id", lit("e2"))

val df4 = df2.union(df3)
```

Content of DF4 is like

```
scala> df4.show(false)
+---+-----------------------------+-----------+
|id |data                         |executor_id|
+---+-----------------------------+-----------+
|1  |[{"number":"n1","data":"d1"}]|e1         |
|1  |[{"number":"n1","data":"d1"}]|e2         |
+---+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

I have to create new json data with `executor_id` as key and `data` as json data, group by `id`. Resultant dataFrame like

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |new_data                                                                |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"e1":[{"number":"n1","data":"d1"}], "e2":[{"number":"n1","data":"d1"}]}|
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Versions:

```
Spark: 2.2
Scala: 2.11
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm not understanding but this part: val df2 = df1.withColumn..  and then this one val df3 = df1.withColumn.. is why they have the same id. The df1 <- is same? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @GamingFelix this is sample code. In real case, df2 and df3 are coming from two  separate source, both having id of same type of entity. After having df2 and df3, I am taking union to merger them in same dataframe df4

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question. I hope someone else can help you

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling to solve this problem from past three days and finally able to work around it using `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`. Here is sample code for same

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{MutableAggregationBuffer, UserDefinedAggregateFunction}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class CustomAggregator extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  override def inputSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType =
    StructType(Array(StructField("key", StringType), StructField("value", ArrayType(StringType))))

  // This is the internal fields you keep for computing your aggregate
  override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(
    Array(StructField("mapData", MapType(StringType, ArrayType(StringType))))
  )

  // This is the output type of your aggregatation function.
  override def dataType = StringType

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  // This is the initial value for your buffer schema.
  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
  }

  // This is how to update your buffer schema given an input.
  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = buffer.getMap(0) + (input.getAs[String](0) -> input.getAs[String](1))
  }

  // This is how to merge two objects with the bufferSchema type.
  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    buffer1.update(0, buffer1.getAs[Map[String, Any]](0) ++ buffer2.getAs[Map[String, Any]](0))
  }

  // This is where you output the final value, given the final value of your bufferSchema.
  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    val map = buffer(0).asInstanceOf[Map[Any, Any]]
    val buff: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()
    for ((k, v) <- map) {
      val valArray = v.asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Any]].array;
      val tmp = {
        for {
          valString <- valArray
        } yield valString.toString
      }.toList.mkString(",")
      buff += "\"" + k.toString + "\":[" + tmp + "]"
    }
    "{" + buff.toList.mkString(",") + "}"
  }
}
```

Now use customAggregator,

```
val ca = new CustomAggregator
val df5 = df4.groupBy("id").agg(ca(col("executor_id"), col("data")).as("jsonData"))
```

Resultant DF is

```
scala> df5.show(false)
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |jsonData                                                               |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"e1":[{"number":"n1","data":"d1"}],"e2":[{"number":"n1","data":"d1"}]}|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Even though I have solved this problem, I am not sure whether this is right way or not. Reasons for my doubts are

1. In places, I have used `Any`. I don't feel this it is correct.
2. For each evaluation, I am creating ListBuffer and many other data type. I am not sure about performance of code.
3. I still have to test code for many dataType like double, date tpye, nested json etc. as data.